# DIY questions vs Woodworking

Tags: discussion, diy

I just asked a question that could easily be on DIY, but I asked it here because I felt it could fit and we need questions!  I'm just wondering what others feel is the line between where the question should be DIY not just could be?

Answer (score 5):

It would be hard to think ahead of all the possible areas of overlap between the two sites and come up exactly where the line should be. Instead, if a question is on-topic on both sites, it should be the author's discretion where to post it. Some things the author might want to keep in mind when deciding:

- Will my question get better answers from handymen/DIYers or from woodworkers?
- Are the tools used more common to handymen/DIYers or woodworkers?
- Which site do I want rep in more?

Whatever the decision, be sure to chose **one**. Cross-posting the same question in two sites is not allowed.

Comment: I'm sure there is a grey area, likely a large one between these two sites, just wondering where something becomes obviously DIY

Comment: I would have said something similar. If the author is not sure then post in Meta or chat. I'm sure the mods can always duke it out with eachother and figure out between the two if their really is any grey area.